# Table doesn't exists error in sequelize postgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm getting the following error when I send a request body to the server which inserts the record into the PostgreSQL database. I tried several ways but still couldn't figure out how the errors are related to the user table when I'm clearly defining them in the model file.

> 2023-03-29 03:23:14.966 UTC [44] ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist at character 13

Database file database.ts

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME!, process.env.DB_USER!, process.env.DB_PASSWORD!, {
  host: process.env.DB_NAME!,
  dialect: 'postgres',
  logging: false,
});

export default sequelize;
```

Model file user.ts

```
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import sequelize from '../database.js';

class User extends Model {
  public id!: number;
  public userName!: string;
  public password!: string;
  public email!: string;
  public dob!: Date;

  public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    userName: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true,
      },
    },
    dob: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'users',
    freezeTableName: true
  }
);

export default User;
```

Controller file userController.ts

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import User from '../models/user.js';

// CREATE a new user
const createUser = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const { userName, password, email, dob } = req.body;

    // Create user
    let user = await User.create({
      userName,
      password,
      email,
      dob,
    });

    res.status(201).json({
        message: `Successfully created the ${userName} user`
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server Error' });
  }
};

export default{
    createUser
}
```

Comment: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#model-synchronization

Comment: Can you please help me with where should I include it from the files I've mentioned above? because I tried including it in the database file and I get "using before the initial error" and in rest I get unable to connect error

Comment: Personally I'd use migrations as indicated [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#synchronization-in-production)